# Using threading.Task to run WCF methods

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf, task-parallel-library

I'm using a generic function to execute wcf service calls - Please see below.
I Just want to make sure I'm doing the right thing:

- The most Important requirement is service calls should be executed in a **seperate thread**. Initially I thought of Backgroundworker then decided to use `Threading.Task` so is it simple as
  `Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() functionToCall.Invoke(serv))` ?
  And get the result `result = t.Result`
- Whats the diffrence if I do:

  > Dim t1 As New Task(Of Object)(Function() functionToCall.Invoke(serv))
  >   t1.Start()
  >   result = t1.Result
- Should I Consider `Parallel`?
- Have I missed anything important?

> **Edit: this function is in client solution's ServiceProxy project**

```
Private Function ServiceCall(ByVal functionToCall As ServiceDelegate(Of IEmpService)) As Object
    Dim channel As New ChannelFactory(Of IEmpService)(_endPoint)
    Dim serv As IEmpService
    Dim result As Object = Nothing

    serv = channel.CreateChannel()

    Try
        Dim t As Task(Of Object) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() functionToCall.Invoke(serv))
        result = t.Result

    Catch exp As Exception 
        CustomLog.Detail(exp)

    Finally
        If channel.State = CommunicationState.Faulted Then
            channel.Abort()
        Else
            channel.Close()
        End If
    End Try

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Your code is blocked at `result = t.Result`. So I see no reason to use  Task instead of calling the method directly.

Comment: L.B is right. When the `Result` property of a `Task` is accessed, the current thread waits for the `Task` to finish. So you start the `Task` and wait for its completion one line below. That's not how the `Task` class is intended to be used. You simply moved the work to another thread but block the first thread, so you don't win anything.

Comment: Thanks. According to you and the calling thread(UI) will be blocked, which is opposite to what I wanted. so how do I do this correctly using `Task`?

Comment: @svick The Project is in vb.net 4.0, I don't have any issues understanding c# but i can't use it in my solution

Comment: @melspring Right, I didn't realize you're using VB (depite the source code you showed). In that case, can you use Visual Basic 2010 (VB 10.0), that comes with Visual Studio 2012? It has some great improvements regarding asynchronous calls.

Comment: @svick If you are refering to .net 4.5 Asynchronous File Operations, then I can't use them. I'm limited to .net 4

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes, the pattern that you've outlined is generally acceptable when you want to make a call asynchronous when there is no other mechanism that you can leverage.

However, in the case of WCF, you are able to generate contracts which conform to the [Asynchronous Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719595%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  When you generate your service references, click on the "Advanced" button and then select "Generate asynchronous operations":

[image: Service Reference advanced options dialog]

When you do that, your service contracts will be generated to return [`IAsyncResult` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx) implementations (`Begin`/`End`) instead of your synchronous operations.

These are preferred to the synchronous operations because it allows you to free up threads that would be blocked when waiting on IO to complete (which is a hardware signal, not something that requires you to hold a thread up).

From there, you can then call the [`FromAsync` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) on the [`TaskFactory` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321401.aspx) to return a [`Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) (which will not block a thread either) that can be used to wait/continue on the call asynchronously.

Comment: Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern(EAP) > Asynchronous Programming Model (APM).

Comment: @JoanComasFdz Task Based pattern > all of them.  The thing is, checking that box only gives you the APM versions, not the EAP versions; you can create the Task-based pattern from either.

Comment: If you can use .net 4.5 yes. Otherwise EAP is way better and simpler.

Comment: @JoanComasFdz Task based pattern was introduced in .NET 4.0, not .NET 4.5.  Also, whether or not EAP or Async patter is better is debatable (I personally don't like the EAP pattern).   The only thing that's definitive is that the Task based pattern is the current recommended pattern above all others.

Comment: Right, it its available in 4 aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do an async call inside method called sync, it does not make sense.

I Suggest you to let this method be sync (remove Task-related code) and use Task/Backgroundworker to call the ServiceCall method instead.

Use a new object with a public method to encapsulate the async call to your sync ServiceCall method and an Event to return the data whenever is received.

And let it to be used like:

```
var caller = new Caller();
caller.Done += { // Your data handling here };
caller.Call(Method1);
```

Here you can play a little bit with this object, passing the returning method logic at the constructor or even a lambda as another parameter to the Call method.

An easy way to implement [Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern(EAP)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nityaprakash/event-based-asynchronous-patterneap/).